# How to implement a callback function while using the twitter api on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, callback

I am working with the twitter api trying to get both tweets and mentions of a particular user however i am only able to get one particular set of tweets at a time. According to a similar question i have seen, a call back function would be needed to solve this problem however i am struggling as i am fairly new to node.js. My problem is i have two client.gets for tweets and mentions but i can only call one at time hence a call back function is needed.

```
 jsonx = {};
  function mentions(x){
    client.get('search/tweets', {q:"@"+x, count:1},
    function (err,data){
      for(var index in data.statuses){
        var tweet = data.statuses[index];
        console.log(tweet.text);
        jsonx[index] = tweet
      }
      res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonx))
    })
  }


  function tweets(y){
    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name:"@"+y, count:1},
    function(err,data) {
      for(var index in data){
        var tweet = data[index];
        console.log(tweet.text);
        jsonx[index] = tweet

      }
           res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonx));
    })
  }
```

Any help on how i can implement the call back function in order to get all the queries from tweets and mentions at the same time.

Thank you
Steve

Comment: Having one callback function to respond to two different client.get calls simultaneously is not possible. Can you tell me why you want to do so, maybe I can suggest a workaround?

Comment: @DevJyotiBehera i want to gather all the tweets i get from both functions and add it to the same JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

Using a twitter client that uses Promises, or even just 'Promisifying' the library you have now would make this really easy.

I recommend Bluebird.js to do this. If you were to go that route, this is how it would work:

1) Require the promise library (after installing via npm)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
```

2) Make a new function to make requests by using Bluebird's promisify method.

```
var clientGet = Promise.promisify(client.get, client);
```

3) Use a aggregate Promise method to make two requests at the same time, such as `join`.

```
Promise.join(
    clientGet('search/tweets', {q:"@"+x, count:1}),
    clientGet('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name:"@"+y, count:1}),
    function(tweets, timeline) {
        //other stuff here, including res.end/json/send/whatever
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store results of both function in single object, you can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module as a best practice.

```
var async = require('async');

async.series([
  function(_cb){
    //call function 1 here and fire _cb callback
  },
  function(_cb){
    //call function 2 here and fire _cb callback
  }
], function(error, response) {
  if(e) {
    //handle error
  }
  else {
    //handle response object here. It will be an array of responses from function_1 and function_2
  }
});
```